# how to clear Terminal of Remix IDE?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, command-line

I want to clear Terminal of Remix IDE like Vs code. If I type clear in vs code terminal, it will clear all previous commands. How do that in Remix Ide?

I tried -

```
clear
cls
```

but nothing works
got this

```
clear is not defined
cls is not defined
```

Comment: You cannot clear the terminal in the remix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a "clear console" button at the top-left of the terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

Clear command not work in REMIX IDE termail to clear termail click the button mentioned in Snap[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remix IDE currently does not support such command. You can visit:

https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remix_commands.html